# Chamar Procedure com retorno Oracle no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oracle, procedure

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e em uma parte do código, preciso chamar uma procedure e ela me retorna um valor.
Como posso fazer isso?

Por enquanto fiz assim e não funcionou:

```
    $sql = "CALL P_VERIFICA_VALORES("
            . $this->_database->escape($dados['tipo']).","
            . $this->_database->escape($dados["setor"])."," // input
            . $dados["operador"]."," // input
            . $dados["mes"]."," // input
            . " @out1" //output
            .")";

    $this->_database->trans_start();
    $this->_database->query($sql);
    $query = $this->_database->query("SELECT @out1 as row_1");
    $this->_database->trans_complete();
```

Retornou o seguinte erro:

Message: oci_execute(): ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar usando o [call_function](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html)

```
$this->db->call_function('P_VERIFICA_VALORES');
```

ou no seu caso, passando os valores

```
$this->db->call_function('P_VERIFICA_VALORES', $param1, $param2, etc..);
```